# How to only show select instance variables in debug variables view?

Tags: android, eclipse

When debugging in eclipse, I want to focus in on the value of one of my instance variables of my activity, declared in this line

```
private int mCurrentLayoutState
```

When I debug my application, is there a way of only seeing what the value of this instance variable is and not all the other ones(of Activity?, or filtering out all the other ones). This is what I am currently seeing in the variables view in debug perspective. 
[image]

The reason I want to do this is to also track changes to my local variables and how this one instance variable is changing. Is there a way to filter all the other instance variables that I am not testing for -mBase,mCalled, mComponent, etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a watch expression to monitor variables (or expressions) of interest.

Right-click on the instance variable, and select "Watch".  This will add an entry to the watch pane.

Comment: wheres the watch pane?

Comment: It should appear right next to the variables pane that you have posted in the image.